# How to calculate average datetime timestamps in python3

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, time, timestamp, libreoffice-calc

I have a code which I have it's performance timestamped, and I want to measure the average of time it took to run it on multiple computers, but I just cant figure out how to use the `datetime` module in python.

Here is how my procedure looks:

1) I have the code which simply writes into a text file the log, where the timestamp looks like

```
t1=datetime.datetime.now()
...
t2=datetime.datetime.now()
stamp= t2-t1
```

And that `stamp` variable is just written in say `log.txt` so in the log file it looks like `0:07:23.160896` so it seems like it's `%H:%M:%S.%f` format.

2) Then I run a second python script which reads in the log.txt file and it reads the `0:07:23.160896` value as a string.

The problem is I don't know how to work with this value because if I import it as a datetime it will also append and imaginary year and month and day to it, which I don't want, I simply just want to work with hours and minutes and seconds and microseconds to add them up or do an average.

For example I can just open it in Libreoffice and add the `0:07:23.160896` to `0:00:48.065130` which will give `0:08:11.226026` and then just divide by 2 which will give `0:04:05.613013`, and I just can't possibly do that in python or I dont know how to do it.

I have tried everything, but neither datetime.datetime, nor datetime.timedelta allows simply multiplication and division like that. If I just do a `y=datetime.datetime.strptime('0:07:23.160896','%H:%M:%S.%f')` it will just give out `1900-01-01 00:07:23.160896` and I can't just take a `y*2` like that, it doesnt allow arithmetic operations, plus if if I convert it into a timedelta it will also multiply the year,which is ridiculous. I simply just want to add and subtract and multiply time.

Please help me find a way to do this, and not just for 2 variables but possibly even a way to calculate the average of an entire list of timestamps like average(['0:07:23.160896' , '0:00:48.065130', '0:00:14.517086',...]) way.

I simply just want a way to calculate the average of many timestamps and give out it's average in the same format, just as you can just select a column in Libreoffice and take the AVERAGE() function which will give out the average timestamp in that column.

Comment: `t2-t1` gives you a timedelta object, not a datetime object. there's no formatting method for timedelta objects, so it might be best if you simply log the seconds as a float number. You can retrieve that with the total_second method of the timedelta objects: `(t2-t1).total_seconds()`.

Answer (score 0):

As you have done, you first read the string into a datetime-object using strptime: `t = datetime.datetime.strptime(single_time,'%H:%M:%S.%f')`

After that, convert the time part of your datestring into a timedelta, so you can easily calculate with times: `tdelta = datetime.timedelta(hours=t.hour, minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second, microseconds=t.microsecond)`

Now you can easily calculate with the timedelta object, and convert at the end of the calculations back into a string by `str(tdsum)`

```
import datetime

times = ['0:07:23.160896', '0:00:48.065130', '0:12:22.324251']

# convert times in iso-format into timedelta list
tsum = datetime.timedelta()
count = 0
for single_time in times:
    t = datetime.datetime.strptime(single_time,'%H:%M:%S.%f')
    tdelta = datetime.timedelta(hours=t.hour, minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second, microseconds=t.microsecond)
    tsum = tsum + tdelta
    count = count + 1

taverage = tsum / count

average_time = str(taverage)
print(average_time)
```